# Showing that a group $G$ as many right cosets as there are left cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. I want to show that there's a bijection $f$ from the set of $G$'s right cosets to the set of $G$'s left cosets, such that $f(Ha) = a^{-1}H$.  I thought about it for a while, but I'm not sure where to begin.  Any hints?

Comment: Can you show that $aH=bH$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $b^{-1}a\in H$? Can you show that $Hc=Hd$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $cd^{-1}\in H$? I think this could help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need this:
$g_1H=g_2H\Leftrightarrow Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$
Then your $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  I didn't know this.

Comment: That shows that your function is well-defined and 1-1.  It is onto because $g\to g^{-1}$ is a bijection of $G$.