# Bijection between left and right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

For a subgroup $H$ of $G$ define the left coset $aH \ (a\in G)$ of $H$ in $G$ as the set of all elements of the form $ah, \ h\in H$. Show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the of left cpsets of $H$ in $G$ and the set of right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

**Proof:** Let $\phi:GH\to HG$ defined by $\phi(gH)=Hg^{-1}$.

1. Mapping $\phi$ is well-defined. In other words, if $g_1H=g_2H$ then we need to show that $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$. Indeed, if $x\in Hg_1^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=h_1g_1^{-1}$ for some $h_1\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^{-1}=(g_1^{-1})^{-1}h_1^{-1}=g_1h_1^{-1}\in g_1H=g_2H$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^{-1}=g_1h_1^{-1}=g_2h_2$ for some $h_2\in H$ 
   $\Rightarrow$ $x=h_2^{-1}g_2^{-1}\in Hg_2^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $Hg_1^{-1}\subset Hg_2^{-1}$. The same reasoning shows that converse inclusion holds. Thus $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ the mapping $\phi$ is well-defined.
2. For $Hg\in HG$ one can find $g^{-1}H\in GH$ such that $\phi(g^{-1}H)=Hg$
3. We'll show that if $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $g_1H=g_2H$.
   If $x\in g_1H$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=g_1h_1$ for some $h_1\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^{-1}=h_1^{-1}g_1^{-1}\in Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^{-1}=h_2g_2^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=g_2h_2^{-2}\in g_2H$. Thus $g_1H\subset g_2H$. The same reasoning shows the converse inclusion, hence $g_1H=g_2H$.

Is this reasoning correct?

**P.S.** Firstly I was considering the mapping defined by $\phi(gH)=Hg$ but i was not able to derive above properties. Can anyone explain why this mapping is "bad"?

Comment: Another duplicate: of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89913/ where there is a one-line proof.

Comment: @DerekHolt, There is no one line proof there. Only remark or something like that.

Comment: The proof by FiniteA got ten upvotes and was accepted.

Comment: $gH\mapsto Hg$ is bad because it's not even a function.

Comment: @Andreas Blass, why it is not a function? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Derek Holt, it is not a proof, it is a hint. But I have provided detailed proof of his hint.

Comment: $gH  \mapsto Hg$ is a function if and only if $Hg=gH\,\forall g \in G$, if and only if $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: In order for $gH\mapsto Hg$ to be a function, we need that, for any input $gH$ there is only one output. In particular, if $gH=g'H$, so $gH$ and $g'H$ are the same input, then the resulting outputs $Hg$ and $Hg'$ must be the same. (Otherwise, we'd get two different outputs for one single input, contrary to the definition of "function".) Now consider any $g\in G$ and any $h\in H$ and notice $gH=ghH$. So to get a function, we'd need $Hg=Hgh$. So $gh\in Hgh=Hg$, i.e., there is $k\in H$ with $gh=kg$. So $ghg^{-1}=k\in H$. Since $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ were arbitrary, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.  
This problem is Problem 5 on p.47.